# Why is the Expected Value not good for this type of question relating to frequency?

Tags: probability

> Number of Persons Living in Household  | Relative Frequency
>
> 1 | 0.36
>
> 2 | 0.28
>
> 3 | 0.14
>
> 4 | 0.15
>
> 5 | 0.05
>
> 5(use 6.3 for avg) | 0.02
>
> ## Predict the expected population of a city that had a total of 8,000 households?

Expected value = $$1(0.36) + 2(0.28) + 3(0.14) + 4(0.15) + 5(0.05) + 6.3(0.02) = 2.31(8000)$$

> b) Why is this information unreliable for predicting the population of an individual city street?

Here I'm sort of stuck on the question, I have the expected value but I cannot for the life of me conjure up a coherent answer that actually satisfies the question. I was thinking maybe the amount of people in each house could be something to write about, but as of now I'm unsure.

Comment: Household populations need not be independent.  They might, for example, be correlated to family income which in turn could certainly be linked to location.

Comment: The numbers of people in different households on a street are not necessarily independent.  Probabilities valid for the population as a whole won't be valid for a particular street.  It could be that you have one street consisting of large homes, and another where all the dwellings are one-room apartments.  There won't be very many large families on the second street.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the responses, i'll use them as a basis for my response.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Same response goes to you as well^

Answer (score 1):

The expected population should be $$ (1\times 0.36 + 2 \times 0.28 + 3 \times 0.14 + 4 \times 0.15 + 5 \times 0.05 + 6.3 \times 0.02) \times 8000 $$

An individual city street usually tends to have similar types of households. So we will very likely need to apply a different distribution to estimate the population on a city street.